# "Git: command not found" error while installing RVM on OS X

Tags: git, ruby, rvm

Working from my command line on Mac OS X Snow Leopard in directory `/Users/michael`, I did the installation line recommended by the RVM site:

```
bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
```

and got this error message which I don't understand...

```
bash: line 152: git: command not found
bash: line 154: git: command not found

ERROR: Unable to clone the RVM repository, attempted both git:// and https://
```

If I've never used GitHub before (at least not that I remember), do I have to do something else before running that install line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X does not ship with Git by default.

Three possibilities:

1. **Easy GUI method:** Download and run [Git OS X installer](https://code.google.com/archive/p/git-osx-installer/downloads). It's not always the latest version of Git, but should work fine for most cases.
2. **OS X Lion only:** Download Xcode 4 from the [Mac App Store](https://web.archive.org/web/20170401072804/https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id448457090?mt=12). It has Git integrated.
3. **Command-line method:** This works on all OS X versions. Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and then run `brew install git`. You need Xcode for that. If you're on Snow Leopard, [register as an Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/register/agree/) (it's free) and then install Xcode 3.